# Where clause with Linq in C# MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to select a field that is from my UserProfile table, RoleID. The parameter passed into this Post method is Username and it is a string from a textbox which is working correctly.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetRoles(string UserName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
        {
             string applyfor = db.Profiles
               .Select(s => s.RoleID)
               .Where(a=>Profile.UserName.Contains(UserName))
               .First();
             ViewBag.ApplyingFor = applyfor;
```

However this gives me Sequence contains no elements.

I've tried several other methods, such as `.Equals()`. I'm pretty sure it is my where clause.

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: `RoleID` is not part of the `Websecurity`, also there is data in the database.

Comment: Is this Entity Framework or LinqToSql or...?

Comment: query seems to confusing, in `a=>Profile.UserName.Contains(UserName)`, I think should be something like `a=>a.<...>`. `Profile.UserName` seems to static class not from db.profiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you break down your code and highlight what each Lambda statement returns you'd see the issue:

```
string applyfor = db.Profiles
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

This most likely returns something like `DbSet<Profile>`.

```
  .Select(s => s.RoleID)
   ^^^^^^
```

This most likely returns `IQueryable<int>`.  At this point you've lost the context of the profile and now only have zero or more `RoleID`s.

So your `a` in the where statement is an `int` Value, you have no way to find a username now, and this where statement literally makes no sense.

```
  .Where(a=>Profile.UserName.Contains(UserName))
```

When you rearrange the Lambda expressions as [Grant Winney's Answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624980/209259) you can see why most of the time a `Select()` is the last thing that normally happens (in simple queries).

I would wager there is no `UserName` on `Profile`. and you want to

```
string applyfor = db.Profiles
                    .Where(p => p.User.Any(u.UserName == UserName))
                    .Select(p => p.RoleID)
                    .First();
```

As a side note, Microsoft Best practice is to [Camel-Case method parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).  So I would recommend your method look like:

```
public ActionResult GetRoles(string userName) // or username
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for the insight. I'll keep that in mind for further in-queries (pun intended) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your Where statement should probably look more like this:

```
 ... .Where(a => a.UserName == Profile.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I learned this week that FirstOrDefault can be used like `.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == Profile.UserName);`

Comment: I would suggest pulling the entire Profile object in debug mode and figure out why the data is not there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
string applyfor = db.Profiles
                    .Where(x => x.UserName == UserName)
                    .Select(x => x.RoleID)
                    .First();
```

Also, if there's a chance you won't find a matching record, use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.First()` and then test for `null`.